# Не удается добавить foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

Пытаюсь добавить FK:

```
set foreign_key_checks = 0;

ALTER TABLE `science_redirects` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk-contest_id` 
FOREIGN KEY (`contest_id`) 
REFERENCES `contests` (`id`) 
ON DELETE CASCADE;

set foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

и мне пишет ошибку: `[Err] 1823 - Failed to add the foreign key constraint 'fk-contest_id' to system tables`. И так еще на куче ключей которые я пытаюсь добавить. Подскажите в чем дело?

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `science_redirects` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `old_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `contest_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `contests` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `number` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_completed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `show_certificates` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `article_price` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `adviser_fullname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `adviser_phone` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `main_text` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `about_text` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `is_active` (`is_active`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2020 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: таблицы - innodb ? они пустые? в science_redirects contest_id - индекс, тип, умолчания?

Comment: @sterx да innodb, не пустые. contest_id - обычное поле типа `int not null` без индекса и умолчания.

Comment: Показывайте DDL обеих таблиц. А также выполните запрос на предмет наличия у реферала значений, отсутствующих у референса.

Comment: @Akina добавил DDL в пост. Второе предложение не понял...

Comment: он сказал, что айдишники связанные ключом могут не соответствовать. потому и рекомендуется добавлять внешний ключ - на пустых таблицах

Comment: @sterx для этого я и отключил проверки ключей перед изменением. На пустых не выйдет. Данных дофига. Это не новый проект.

Comment: Типы данных совпадают. Теперь проверьте данные: `SELECT DISTINCT sr.contest_id FROM science_redirects sr LEFT JOIN contests с ON sr.contest_id = c.id WHERE c.id IS NULL`. Ибо структурно противопоказаний нет: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cb28ef8b1d406646fd6e47fb86b10744). PS. *я и отключил проверки ключей* Изменение структуры делаете через консольный клиент? если нет - убедитесь, что все три запроса выполняются в одном Connection!!!

Comment: @Akina так не выходит почему-то: `[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'c.id' in 'where clause'`. Да это не надо - я же говорю я отключил проверки ключей. Вон первая строка. К тому же была бы другая ошибка.

Comment: *я же говорю я отключил проверки ключей. Вон первая строка.* ВНИМАТЕЛЬНО читай PS к предыдущему каменту. *не выходит почему-то* Копипастил или руками перенабирал? небось первое...

Comment: @Akina не видел PS. Делаю через navicat. И я уверен что он использует одно соединение для каждой отдельной вкладки. Что же касается запроса: да копипастил, сейчас перенабрал и сработало - ничего не выбралось.

Comment: *Делаю через navicat. И я уверен* Для проверки - перед и после UPDATE добавь `SELECT @@foreign_key_checks;`... и всё-таки попробуй ALTER через консольного клиента.

Comment: @Akina да, я уже так проверял. Возвращает 0. Через консоль тоже не выходит. Вообще я думаю что что-то с настройками mysql. Я недавно сервер переустанавливал и долго настраивал все... Юзал mysqltuner в частности.

Comment: не понимаю людей, которые заведомо в идентификаторы добавляют символы типа `-`, из-за которых придется всегда и везде при использовании добавлять кавычки

Comment: @teran чертов гений!!! Когда заменил на `fk_contest_id` заработало!!! Странно это конечно, ведь кавычки были... Что же касается дефиса - то так было в каком-то примере в интернете. Я вообще изначально называл ключи также как столбцы, но в какой-то момент это тоже стало не работать.

Comment: @teran хотя нет стоп. Не работает. Один раз сработало, удалил, опять не работает (даже без дефиса). У меня кстати уже так бывало. 50 раз не работает, один раз сработает и это даже без каких-либо изменений в коде...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась сама собой. Оказывается название ключа должно быть уникальным для всей базы. Т.е. называть ключ надо примерно по такому правилу: `fk-table-column`, т.к. в разных таблицах могут быть столбцы с одинаковыми именами (что собственно у меня и было), а вот имя таблицы уже уникально для всей базы. Плохо только что об этом добром в ошибке не написало, а вместо этого какую-то дичь про "system tables" орало... После смены стратегии именования все ключи успешно добавились.